# Balanced Shortest[] and string patterns

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

The pattern `Shortest["A"~~__~~"B"]` is oriented : It assumes the text is read from left to right and it takes the text between the first `"A"` and the next `"B"`. Any `"A"` after the first `"A"` is considered as normal text.

I want to select a text between the **last** `"A"` and the first `"B"`.

This problem can be solved with `Except["A"]`, but I don't find a clean solution when `"A"` is a string with more than one character.

Example :

```
StringCases[
 "blabla ...Hello Hello ... blabla ... Goodbye Goodbye ..",  
 Shortest["Hello" ~~ ___ ~~ "Goodbye"]
]
```

gives:  `{"Hello Hello ... blabla ... Goodbye"}`.

I would like to get  `{"Hello ... blabla ... Goodbye"}`.

**Edit**

If there are several sequences `"Hello...Goodbye"` (not nested),
I wish to get a list of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 shortestStringCases[str_String, from_String, to_String] := 
   StringCases[ str, (from ~~ mid___ ~~ to) /; StringFreeQ[mid, {from, to}]]
 shortestStringCases["blah X blah X first Y blah X blah X second Y", "X", "Y"]
 (* {"X first Y", "X second Y"} *)
```

Comment: What I like in the solution `shortestStringCases[]` is the clarity of the code. One see immediately what it does and that it is balanced. May be not efficient but good as specification.

Comment: This requires that from and to are literal strings right? And not StringExpressions.

Comment: @Kvothe, you are right.

Comment: This solution gives wrong results for the cases like `shortestStringCases["gffghtomatomato12345iconiconictomatomatoiconiconic","tomato","iconic"]`. But +1 for the clarity of the code.

Comment: More general version of `shortestStringCases`, which works correcly with multicharacter boundaries: `shortestStringCases[str_String,from_String,to_String]:=StringCases[str,match:(from~~mid___~~to)/;StringFreeQ[StringTake[match,{2,-2}],{from,to}]]`.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to work:

```
StringCases["blabla ...Hello Hello ... blabla ... Goobye Goobye ..", 
 Longest[___ ~~ a : "Hello"] ~~ b : Shortest[___ ~~ "Goobye"] :> a ~~ b]
```

**Update**

If there are multiple substrings to extract you can use recursion:

```
extractbetween[str_, x_, y_] := Module[{f},
  f[s_] := StringCases[s, 
   Longest[a___ ~~ x] ~~ b : Shortest[___ ~~ y] :> {f[a], x ~~ b}];
  Flatten@f@str]

extractbetween["blah X first Y blah X second Y X third Y", "X", "Y"]
(* {"X first Y", "X second Y", "X third Y"} *)
```

Comment: Interesting, but I have forgotten to mention that there are several sequences   Hello Hello... Goodbye in the same text. That's a problem with your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution is just to replace your boundary words with single characters. I think what you are venturing into is something akin to look-behind, which I don't think is supported. Anyways here's how I would do it:

```
boundary = {"Hello", "Goobye"};
limits = {"\[FormalCapitalX]", "\[FormalCapitalY]"};

shift[str_, from_, to_] := StringReplace[str, Rule @@@ Transpose[{from, to}]]
```

Just to have more then one match, I changed the test string

```
test = "blabla ...Hello Hello ... blabla ... Goobye
            Goobye .... Hello ... blabla2... Goobye";

shift[#, limits, boundary] & /@ 
  StringCases[shift[test, boundary, limits], 
  Shortest[limits[[1]] ~~ (Except[limits[[1]]] ...) ~~ limits[[2]]]]
(* {"Hello ... blabla ... Goobye"  , "Hello ... blabla2... Goobye"}  *)
```

Depending on your input, the substitution characters might need to be more carefully selected.

Comment: Until yet I use only ASCII character (in this problem). I must see how string-patterns interacts with special characters. Further information in half a day.

Comment: I think the trick is that Except doesn't accept a String apart from when the String represents a special character. Strange. May be there's a more general way to force Except to take a String ?

Comment: @andre I would expect it's a case of how the regular expression is implimented. To get some feeling for it [here's a video of converting regular expressions into finite state automaton](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwsU2LPs85U). The thing is that deteting when you reach a single token is different from keeping a seperate memory of which tokens you have been through and detecting whether they make up a specific series.

Comment: (3 years later) The right solution with a regular expression has just been added by Alexey Popkov. See below his answer to my question.

Answer (score 4):

### UPDATE: Universal balanced `Shortest`

In [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/272621/280) answer I managed to find a really universal solution through regular expressions:

```
Clear[ShortestStringBetween]
Options[ShortestStringBetween] = {"IncludeBoundaries" -> False, 
   "BoundaryOverlaps" -> False};
ShortestStringBetween[str_String, start_String, end_String, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{bInclude = OptionValue["IncludeBoundaries"],
    bOvelap = OptionValue["BoundaryOverlaps"]},
   Which[
    bInclude && Not[bOvelap],
    StringCases[str, RegularExpression[
      StringTemplate["`START`(?:(?!`END`).(?<!`START`))*`END`"][
       <|"START" -> start, "END" -> end|>]]],
    Not[bInclude] && Not[bOvelap],
    StringCases[str, RegularExpression[
       StringTemplate["`START`((?:(?!`END`).(?<!`START`))*)`END`"][
        <|"START" -> start, "END" -> end|>]] -> "$1"],
    Not[bInclude] && bOvelap,
    StringCases[str, RegularExpression[
      StringTemplate["(?<=`START`)(?:(?!`END`).(?<!`START`))*(?=`END`)"][
       <|"START" -> start, "END" -> end|>]]],
    bInclude && bOvelap,
    StringCases[str, match : RegularExpression[
        StringTemplate["(?<=`START`)(?:(?!`END`).(?<!`START`))*(?=`END`)"][
         <|"START" -> start, "END" -> end|>]] :> StringJoin[start, match, end]]
    ]];
```

Note that the `start` and `end` parameters are directly inserted into `RegularExpression` and therefore must be regular expressions in the *Mathematica* format. And since PCRE (on which `RegularExpression` is based) doesn't support infinite repetition within a [lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind), the `start` parameter [must be](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width) a fixed-length regexp or contain alternations of different but pre-determined lengths (for example, `"cat|raccoon"`). The `end` parameter has no such restriction. But I haven't tested how this implementation behaves with non-fixed length parameters.

It works correctly in the all test cases:

```
front = "Hello";
back = "Goodbye";
str = "blabla ...Hello Hello ... blabla ... Goodbye Goodbye ..";
ShortestStringBetween[str, front, back, "IncludeBoundaries" -> True]
```

> ```
> {"Hello ... blabla ... Goodbye"}
> ```

```
front = "tomato";
back = "iconic";
str = "gffghtomatomato12345iconiconictomatomatoiconiconic";
ShortestStringBetween[str, front, back]
```

> ```
> {"12345", ""}
> ```

```
front = "NotEnd";
back = "End";
str = "NotEndNotEnd1234NotEnd";
ShortestStringBetween[str, front, back]
ShortestStringBetween[str, front, back, "BoundaryOverlaps" -> True]
```

> ```
> {"Not"}
> ```

> ```
> {"Not", "1234Not"}
> ```

---

### Original answer

One can use here regular expression with *[Negative Lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#negative-lookahead)* `(?!regex)` *Before the Match* in the same way as shown in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111236/280) answer:

```
text="blabla ...Hello .. blabla .. Hello ... blabla ... Goodbye .. blabla .. Goodbye ... \
blabla ...Hello Hello ... blabla ... blabla ... Goodbye .. blabla .. Goodbye ... ";

StringCases[text, "Hello" ~~ RegularExpression["(?:(?!Hello).)*?"] ~~ "Goodbye"]
```

> ```
> {"Hello ... blabla ... Goodbye", "Hello ... blabla ... blabla ... Goodbye"}
> ```

Or using pure regexes:

```
StringCases[text, RegularExpression["Hello(?:(?!Hello).)*?Goodbye"]]
```

> ```
> {"Hello ... blabla ... Goodbye", "Hello ... blabla ... blabla ... Goodbye"}
> ```

A detailed description of this method can be found [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).