# Finding strings in Web Code

Tags: string-manipulation, searching

I haven't found an answer that solves my problem, although I think it's actually a simple one. It seems hard to me because I don't have a lot of experience with string patterns.

I have a Web Code like

```html
...<td, class=test, >strings1</td>...<td, class=test, >strings2</td>...
```

that I have imported using

```
v = Import[*url*, "Table"]
```

I want to find these strings *string1*, *string2*, etc., but when I use `StringCases` like

```
StringCases[ToString[v], "class=test, >" ~~ x__ ~~ "</td>" -> x]
```

The code will return everything between the first `class=test, >` and the last `</td>`, resulting in something like

```html
strings1</td>...<td, class=test, >strings2`
```

But I want all the strings between each paired `class=test, >` and `</td>`, I have tried to use `Overlap` without success.

Comment: It is a widely (and justifiably) held view that one should not use regular expressions (or equivalent, as in this case) to parse [X]HTML. You will probably be better off importing as HTML or XML and then manipulating these results symbolically using the [XML package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/XML/guide/XMLPackage.html).

Comment: @OleksandrR. Agree, but I recall XML import and parsing in *Mathematica* is very time consuming. So I have used regular expressions in the past out of speed necessity.

Comment: Your web code has syntax errors in it. The commas after `<td` aren't correct.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Shortest` if the sub-strings  of the form `<td, class=test, >...</td>` don't contain nested sub-strings of the form `<td, class=test, >` or `</td>`. If they do, follow [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18193/balanced-shortest-and-string-patterns).

```
v = "...<td, class=test, >strings1</td>...<td, class=test, >strings2</td>..";
StringCases[v, Shortest["<td, class=test, >" ~~ x__ ~~ "</td>"] -> x]
```

> {"strings1", "strings2"}

Comment: Not sure, but I would rather say : You can use `Shortest` if the 2 following conditions are respected : 1) Your targeted `<td, class=test, >...</td>` doesn't contain nested sub-strings of the form `<td, class=test, >` or `</td>` 2) Your targeted `<td, class=test, >...</td>` is not enclosed in another `<td, class=test, >...</td>`. If it is the case and if 1) is respected follow the link

Answer (score 0):

Using my Excel mindset and assuming all the "class=test, >" are matched 
with a "<\td" I would do something like:

```
str = "...<td, class=test, >strings1</td>...<td, class=test, >strings2</td>..."

starts = StringPosition[str, "class=test, >"]
startpositions = Flatten@Take[starts, All, {2}] + 1
ends = StringPosition[str, "</td"]
endpositions = Flatten@Take[ends, All, {1}] - 1
segments = Transpose[{startpositions, endpositions}]

strings = StringTake[str, segments]
propersentence = "I found " <> Riffle[strings, {" and "}] <> "."
Speak[propersentence]
```

or similar.