# StringPattern to remove markers around text

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I am not able to figure the StringPattern to use to remove  markers in string.

This is the input.

```
lst = {{1, 2, "this is a test", 4}, {Pi, 20, xy, 10}};
buf = ToString@TeXForm@lst
```

which gives

```
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
     1 & 2 & \text{this is a test} & 4 \\
     \pi  & 20 & \text{xy} & 10 \\
    \end{array}
\right)
```

I need to remove all the places where this pattern shows up `\text{.....}` and replace it with just  what is inside `....`. i.e. strip out the `\text{` and the closing `}` on the other side. For each such instance in the input.

So the above should become

```
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
     1 & 2 & this is a test & 4 \\
     \pi  & 20 & xy & 10 \\
    \end{array}
\right)
```

I tried many things. Tried also using `RegularExpression`.

One attempt:

```
StringReplace[buf, "\\text{" ~~ x___ ~~ "}" .. :> x]
```

But this has a problem. It does not stop at the first closing `}`, but goes all the way to the ending `}` in the string, ending up with

```
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & this is a test} & 4 \\
 \pi  & 20 & \text{xy} & 10 \\
\end{array
\right)
```

Notice, it went all the way to the end, and removed the `}` after `{array`.

I did not know how to tell it to stop at the *first* `}` it sees after it sees `\text{`. And that is what I am struggling with. I know I wrote `x__` but I needed to do this, so I can pick out the `x`.

Any idea how to do this? Either using StringPattern or ReqgularExpression will work.

Comment: closely related: [Get the wrong result using the StringCase function and Shortest option](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72293/5478)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With both `StringPattern` and `RegularExpression` the problem is greediness: wildcards will try to match as much as possible. With `StringPattern` this can be fixed using `Shortest`:

```
StringReplace[buf, "\\text{" ~~ Shortest[x___] ~~ "}" :> x]
```

With a regular expression a quantifier can be made ungreed with `?` (e.g. `{(.*?)}`), but when you're going that way, you can actually write a safer regular expression using a negated character class:

```
StringReplace[buf, RegularExpression["\\\\text{(.*?)}"] :> "$1"]
```

Which gives the same result.

Both of these have one issue though: they're not entirely safe. When your actual string contains `}`, then they will stop at that. Consider:

```
lst = {"abc", "x}y", "123"};
buf = ToString@TeXForm@lst
```

This gives:

```
\{\text{abc},\text{x$\}$y},123\}
```

And using either solution will turn it into:

```
\{abc,x$\$y},123\}
```

I think to fix this, only a regular expression approach is viable, which knows exactly what characters (or combinations) are allowed within the `{...}`:

```
StringReplace[buf, RegularExpression["\\\\text{((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\}])*)}"] :> "$1"]
```

Which gives

```
\{abc,x$\}$y,123\}
```

as expected.

Comment: Thanks. It is the `Shortest` which I did not know to use.

Comment: +1, but all those escapes in the penultimate snippet are making me dizzy. :)

Comment: @J.M. hm yeah, it's definitely annoying me that there is no sort of verbatim string syntax in Mathematica whenever working with regex. :/

Answer (score 0):

A form without [`RegularExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularExpression.html) that I believe works on Martin's second example:

```
lst = {"abc", "x}y", "123"};
buf = ToString @ TeXForm @ lst;

StringReplace[buf, "\\text{" ~~ Shortest[a___] ~~ b : Except["\\"] ~~ "}" :> a <> b]
```

> ```
> "\\{abc,x$\\}$y,123\\}"
> ```