# Pattern match Shortest BlankNullSequence in SequencePosition

Tags: pattern-matching, sequence

Apologies if this has an answer somewhere but I can't find it.

From the examples for SequencePosition we are shown that

```
SequencePosition[{a, b, b, a, b, b, b}, {Repeated[b]}]
```

> {{2, 3}, {3, 3}, {5, 7}, {6, 7}, {7, 7}}

If I change the pattern:

```
SequencePosition[{a, b, b, a, b, b, b}, {b, ___, b}]
```

> {{2, 7}, {3, 7}, {5, 7}, {6, 7}}

Now I want to match the shortest lengths of blank null sequences, so I guess my desired outputs is `{{2,3}, {3,5}, {5,6}, {6,7}`. But `Shortest` doesn't seem to change anything:

```
SequencePosition[{a, b, b, a, b, b, b}, {b, Shortest[___], b}]
```

> {{2, 7}, {3, 7}, {5, 7}, {6, 7}}

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try `SequencePosition[{a, b, b, a, b, b, b}, {b, Except[b] ..., b}]`.

Comment: I suppose this is the same issue, yet I'm not sure: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72283/5478

Comment: That's strange: looks like `Shortest` is simply ignored! The expected behavior should be as in `SequencePosition[{a, b, c, d}, {Shortest[__]}]` and `SequencePosition[{a, b, c, d}, {__}]`. I suspect a bug.

Comment: @Kuba [That](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72283/5478) thread is about pattern matching in strings (implemented via PCRE), this question is about matching of usual patterns. So these questions are completely independent.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov not entirely. There are no RegExps on OPs side there. They will be after translation from MMA patterns, so it is about `Shortest` too. Yet I won't insist, I'm not an expert in pattern matching.