# Why does Shortest not work inside SequencePosition?

Tags: list-manipulation, bugs, pattern-matching

Why does [`Shortest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Shortest.html) not work in a [`SequencePosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html) call? The following two commands return the same answer:

```
SequencePosition[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {a_, ___, b_}]
(*    {{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}}    *)
SequencePosition[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {a_, Shortest[___], b_}]
(*    {{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}}    *)
```

I would prefer it if the second one returned

```
(*    {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}    *)
```

Do you know how to achieve this behavior?

Notice that the closely related [`StringPosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringPosition.html) works as expected:

```
StringPosition["12345", a_ ~~ ___ ~~ b_]
(*    {{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}}    *)
StringPosition["12345", a_ ~~ Shortest[___] ~~ b_]
(*    {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}    *)
```

Related:

- [Longest and Shortest won't work in ReplaceList?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120037/26598)
- [Pattern match Shortest BlankNullSequence in SequencePosition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114774/26598)

Comment: Forwarded to [Wolfram Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/) as unexpected behavior.

Comment: Confirmed by Wolfram Support as unexpected behavior [CASE:4269719].

Comment: It's no surprise `StringPosition` doesn't share the problem - it is based on a common (textual) regular expression matcher (was it PCRE?), while the pattern matcher in Mathematica is their own.