# How to use Shortest[___] with Sequence pattern matching?

Tags: pattern-matching, sequence

[`Shortest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Shortest.html)[] doesn't appear to work with [`Sequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) s. Is this a bug or a feature? What can I do to force the following [`SequenceCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html) to work?

```
In[1]:= SequenceCases[{1,1,2,2,0,0,2,2,2,1},{2,2,Shortest[___],2,2}]
Out[1]= {{2,2,0,0,2,2,2}}
```

Expected output:

```
Out[1]= {{2,2,0,0,2,2}}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Report it to: support@wolfram.com

Comment: @Daniel Huber will do

Comment: Essentially the same question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114774/1871 But that question doesn't receive enough attention, either.