# Extract string words from string

Tags: string-manipulation, text

Hi i'm new to programming and it's my first question, so please go easy on me. 
I want to create a function that extracts text which is between `BEGIN` and `>`. For example with a string of text:

```
str="Random stuff here TEXT BEGIN extract this text > here is other stuff >"
```

The function should extract the text between `BEGIN` and `>`. The text in-between, can be anything from symbols like `\n` or be another string.

I know I can get every instance of `BEGIN` with position,

```
Position[StringSplit[str],"BEGIN"]
```

but how do I get the position of the next instance of `>` from `BEGIN`, so I can extract the text in-between? Or is there a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: Recommended reading: [(72283)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72283/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
StringCases[str, "BEGIN" ~~ x : Shortest[___] ~~ ">" :> x]
```

> {" extract this text "}

```
StringCases["Random stuff here TEXT BEGIN extract \n this text > here is other stuff >", 
 "BEGIN" ~~ x : Shortest[___] ~~ ">" :> x]
```

> {" extract
>      this text "}

To trim the white space around extracted string use `StringTrim` on the previous results or on the right hand side of the replacement rule:

```
StringCases[str, "BEGIN" ~~ x : Shortest[___] ~~ ">" :> StringTrim[x]]
```

> {"extract this text"}

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "Random stuff here TEXT BEGIN extract this text > here is other stuff >";

StringTake[str, #]&[Last@First@StringPosition[str, #] & /@ {"BEGIN", ">"} + {2, -2}]
```