# How to use `Shortest` for pattern matching?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

For the string `((!@#))`, the shortest match for the pattern `"("~~__~~")"` should be `"(!@#)"`, but

```
StringCases["((!@#))", Shortest["(" ~~ __ ~~ ")"]]
```

Returns with `((!@#)`. What went wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: duplicate of [(72283)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72283/142).

Comment: A concise explanation of what went wrong with your code is in the question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18193/5467.   
The question suggests a solution with `Except[]`. The complete suggested solution is : `StringCases["((!@#))", Shortest["(" ~~ Except["("] .. ~~ ")"]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Last@StringCases["((!@#))", Shortest["(" ~~ __ ~~ ")"], Overlaps -> True]
```

[image]