# How can one represent a string pattern with prohibited substrings?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, regular-expressions

Say I have the following string: `"<hello>something WRONG</hello><hello>something else</hello>"`

I am trying to find code that works like the following:

```
StringCases[string, 
 "<hello>" ~~ 
   something : StringPatternThatDoesntContainString["WRONG"] ~~ 
   "</hello>" :> something]
```

I'm trying to find all the string between hello tags that don't contain the "WRONG" string.

Answer (score 11):

A solution using regular expression with *[Negative Lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#negative-lookahead)* `(?!regex)` *Before the Match*:

```
string = "<hello>something WRONG</hello><hello>something else</hello><hello>WRONG</hello>";

StringCases[string, 
 "<hello>" ~~ st : RegularExpression["(?:(?!WRONG).)*?"] ~~ "</hello>" :> st]
```

> ```
> {"something else"}
> ```

An alternative solution using pure regexes (should be more efficient):

```
StringCases[string, RegularExpression["(?ms)<hello>((?:(?!WRONG).)*?)</hello>"] :> "$1"]
```

> ```
> {"something else"}
> ```

A detailed description of this method can be found [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).

---

### UPDATE

Performance comparison of the three methods including the improved [solution by march](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111213/280) (timings for version 10.4.1 on Win7 x64):

```
string = "<hello>something WRONG</hello><hello>something</hello><hello>something \
else</hello><hello>WRONG</hello>";
stringBig = StringJoin@ConstantArray[string, 3*^2];

First@AbsoluteTiming[
  r1 = StringCases[stringBig, 
    "<hello>" ~~ Shortest[st__] ~~ "</hello>" /; StringFreeQ[st, "WRONG"] :> st]]
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  r2 = StringCases[stringBig, 
    "<hello>" ~~ st : RegularExpression["(?:(?!WRONG).)*?"] ~~ "</hello>" :> st]]
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  r3 = StringCases[stringBig, 
    RegularExpression["(?ms)<hello>((?:(?!WRONG).)*?)</hello>"] :> "$1"]]
r1 === r2 === r3
```

> ```
> 14.5705
>
> 0.00302571
>
> 0.00242202
>
> True
> ```

As one can see, the `StringExpression` (`~~`) solution with `Condition` (`/;`) is more than 3 orders of magnitude slower than `StringExpression` without it. What is unexpected is that pure `RegularExpression` solution is slower than `StringExpression` without `Condition`. This topic was [discussed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25677/280) before but an explanation was not found.

And here is the output obtained with the same code using version 8.0.4 on the same machine:

> ```
> 78.8455097
>
> 0.0030002
>
> 0.0040002
>
> True
> ```

As one can see, there is significant speedup for string pattern with `Condition` in version 10.4.1 as compared to 8.0.4.

Comment: I see you are timing some string matching operations.  I haven't gotten around to that yet.  I see that the one using `Condition` is several orders of magnitude worse than the others, *perhaps* an indication of slow-down induced by more generalized matching.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard As I understand, `Condition` is a top-level Kernel function called from the PCRE library. So the huge slowdown is expected in any case as compared to pure PCRE processing. What I wanted to show in my updated answer is that the situation with version 10.4.1 is much better than it was with version 8.0.4: the former is about 5 times faster (and for larger lists the difference is even higher!). The improvement is seemingly due to more efficient implementation of the callback from PCRE to the Kernel (other timings don't differ so much).

Answer (score 10):

```
str = "<hello>something</hello><hello>something</hello><hello>something WRONG</hello>";
StringCases[str, 
 "<hello>" ~~ Shortest[st__] ~~ "</hello>" /; StringFreeQ[st, "WRONG"] :> st]
```

> ```
> {"something", "something"}
> ```

(With hat tip to [Alexey Popkov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280/alexey-popkov) for adding robustness via `Shortest`).

Comment: Your current solution fails with for example `str = "<hello>something</hello><hello>something2</hello>";`. You should replace `st__` with `Shortest[st__]` to avoid this: by default string patterns are greedy (in contrast with the usual patterns).

Comment: @Alexey. Agreed. I will modify it.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to update the output in your answer (which you forgot to update) and to add more representative `str` for testing the solution. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov. Yeah! No problem. I hadn't had my morning coffee yet.