# How To Extract String Between Brackets/Parentheses

Tags: string-manipulation

I have the following file:

```
Fulltext = {"Apple Hospitality REIT, Inc. (APLE) Market Cap: $4.04B", "Arena Pharmaceuticals, Inc. (ARNA) Market Cap: $749.57M ", "Argo Group International Holdings, Ltd. (AGII) Market Cap:$1.81B ", "Armstrong Flooring, Inc. (AFI) Market Cap: $475.81M ", "Atlas Financial Holdings, Inc. (AFH) Market Cap: $183.47M ", "Avis Budget Group, Inc. (CAR) Market Cap: $2.6B "};
```

I just want to extract the following:

```
WhatIwant = {APLE, ARNA, AGII, AFI, AFH, CAR};
```

Although this example has only six extractions, I am looking for a more generic function that can be used to extract any number of strings that are within parentheses. Any help is greatly appreciated.

For clarity: I am importing a text file from a website using the following codes:

```
importeddata = 
  Import["http://www.nasdaq.com/earnings/earnings-calendar.aspx?date=\
2017-Aug-07", "Data"];
calanderdate = Flatten[importeddata[[2, 1]], 2];
calanderdate2 = calanderdate[[4 ;; Length[calanderdate] - 1]];
```

The `calanderdate2` has a lot of companies' names and their ticker symbols in the middle within parentheses. I want to extract only the ticker symbols. Thanks

Comment: Try something like `StringCases[str, "("~~s:Except["("|")"]..~~")":>s]`

Comment: b3m2a1, I think it serves my need. If this is not a dump question or is not repeated, can you please answer this question? Thank you for the prompt reply.

Comment: To be sure you should also use `Shortest`, and if I remember correctly, the most efficient way uses `RegularExpression`.

Comment: @JEM_Mosig `Shortest` isn't actually necessary because of both of the `Except` cases and a raw `Shortest` fails. I'm not surprised `RegularExpression` wins though. Post an answer with that and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a timing comparison of equivalent solutions (*Mathematica* 11.1.1 on Windows 7 x64):

```
str = StringRepeat["asdasd (((( ) asd) aasdasd)  (a ) asd) (asd) )asdasd )", 1000000];

StringCases[str, "(" ~~ s : RegularExpression["[^()]*"] ~~ ")" :> s]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* => {2.51031, Null} *)

StringCases[str, "(" ~~ s : Except["(" | ")"] ... ~~ ")" :> s]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* => {2.70701, Null} *)

StringCases[str, "(" ~~ s : RegularExpression["[^()]"] ... ~~ ")" :> s]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* => {3.08826, Null} *)

StringCases[str, RegularExpression["\\(([^()]*)\\)"] -> "$1"]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* => {5.29573, Null} *)

StringCases[str, RegularExpression["(?<=\\()[^()]*(?=\\))"]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* => {7.71658, Null} *)
```

It is surprising that substring extraction via numbered capturing group (`RegularExpression["\\(([^()]*)\\)"] -> "$1"`) is so inefficient as compared to equivalent substring extration via named capturing group (`"(" ~~ s : RegularExpression["[^()]*"] ~~ ")" :> s`).

If you don't want to get empty string `""` from `"()"` you should replace `*` with `+` in the regexes:

```
StringCases["()", "(" ~~ s : RegularExpression["[^()]+"] ~~ ")" :> s]

(* => {} *)
```

Comment: @ Alexey, thank you for your time and response.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another option:

```
StringCases["asdasd (((( ) asd) aasdasd)  (a ) asd) (asd) )asdasd )", 
 "(" ~~ s : Except["(" | ")"] .. ~~ ")" :> s]

{" ", "a ", "asd"}
```

Note why both of the [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) in the [`Except`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Except.html) are needed:

```
StringCases["asdasd (((( ) asd) aasdasd)  (a ) asd) (asd) )asdasd )", 
 "(" ~~ s : Except["("] .. ~~ ")" :> s]

{" ) asd) aasdasd", "a ) asd", "asd) )asdasd "}

StringCases["asdasd (((( ) asd) aasdasd)  (a ) asd) (asd) )asdasd )", 
 "(" ~~ s : Except[")"] .. ~~ ")" :> s]

{"((( ", "a ", "asd"}
```

Comment: Maybe you find `Shortest` opaque because of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18193/5467). Once you have understood that `Shortest`is "oriented" (ie not balanced, not symetrical), you feel far better.

Comment: @andre it's mostly that a basic `Shortest[__]` does not always return what one expects.

Comment: andre is right: `Shortest` is translated into the corresponding *lasy* quantifier (`*?` or `+?`) what explains the observed "unexpected" behaviour. There was a dedicated question on the difference in behaviour of `Shortest` in usual patterns and string patterns.

Answer (score 3):

A  possibilty is to use `Shortest`:

`StringCases["asdasd (((( ) asd) aasdasd)  (a ) asd) (asd) )asdasd )",Shortest[ "("~~s:Except["("]..~~")"]:>s]`

> {" ", "a ", "asd"}

Though I'm not aware of any advantages too use this form (with `Shortest`) rather than @b3m2a1's solution (with `Except[Alternative[...]]`)

Comment: @ andre, thank you for your time and response.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when looking for citations in text and found this article here useful [Shortest and string patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18193/balanced-shortest-and-string-patterns). I for myself use the following function to do the job:

```
midString[text_String,{leftDelimiter_,rightDelimiter_}]:=
Union @ 
Flatten @ 
StringCases[text,leftDelimiter~~Shortest[x__]~~rightDelimiter->x, Overlaps->False]
```

It also can be used to extract filenames form a name containing albs the directory name. In your case:

```
    midString[#, {"(", ")"}] & /@ Fulltext // Flatten
(* {"APLE","ARNA","AGII","AFI","AFH","CAR"} *)
```

To overcome the problem mentioned in the linked thread you can use a more sophisticated version:

```
citations[text_String, {leftDelimiter_, rightDelimiter_}] :=
 StringCases[
  text, (leftDelimiter ~~ mid___ ~~ rightDelimiter) /; 
   StringFreeQ[mid, {leftDelimiter, rightDelimiter}]]
```

Comment: @ mgamer, thank you for your time and response.

Comment: @ramesh: You´re welcome :-)