# problem of `Shortest` and `StartOfLine` in string match

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Say I have the code below to extract those lines with "::" in a string snippet:

```
StringCases["fdsa
fds
fdsa
ss::x
x::2",
Shortest[StartOfLine ~~ __ ~~ "::" ~~ __ ~~ EndOfLine]][[1]]
```

However, the first occurrence involves more lines than I want:

```
    fdsa
    fds
    fdsa
    ss::x
```

As I would assume first three lines should be excluded by using `Shortest` and `StartOfLine`, why does Mathematica give an answer like that?

Comment: Why ? Answer in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18193/5467) where the mentionned "A" is StartOfLine in your case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string subpattern `__` in `StartOfLine ~~ __ ~~ "::"` will match any characters, including line endings.  That is why the first match spanned line boundaries: it was the "shortest" match starting from the first start-of-line found.

To prevent this behaviour, we must explicitly exclude line endings.  For example:

```
StringCases["fdsa
fds
fdsa
ss::x
x::2",
Shortest[StartOfLine ~~ Except["\r"|"\n"].. ~~ "::" ~~ __ ~~ EndOfLine]][[1]]

(* "ss::x" *)
```

The line ending characters are specified explicitly since `Except` in string patterns can only be applied to single characters -- and line endings are multi-character in general across platforms.

The modifier `Shortest` might imply that it will find the shortest possible match, but it really only means the "shortest match starting from the initial search point".  This point is elaborated further in [(72283)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72283/142).  The present question might be considered to be a duplicate of that other question, but a distinction might be drawn due to the added complication of applying `Except` to line endings.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringCases["fdsa
 fds
 fdsa
 ss::x
 x::2", 
 Except["\n" ] .. ~~ "::" ~~ Except["\n"] ..]
```

> {"ss::x", "x::2"}